# RxJava stream transformation

Tags: rx-java2

I have the following functions declared in the repo:

```
fun loadAllNotifications(): Single<List<Notification>>

fun insertAll(notifications: List<Notification>): Completable
```

What I'd like to do is to `loadAllNotifications()` and then for each `Notification` reset its `isOpened` flag to `false` by doing something like

```
val updatedNotification = currentNotification.copy(isOpened = false)
```

Once I have a list of Notifications with the `isOpened` set to `false`, I'd like to pass this list into `insertAll(list)`

How would I do the above in a single RxChain? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
loadAllNotifications()
        .flatMapObservable { Observable.fromIterable(it) }
        .map { it.copy(isOpened = false) }
        .toList()
        .flatMapCompletable{ insertAll(it) }
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks very much!